# Type missmatch cannot convert from String to int

Tags: java, arrays, types

The goal of the application is as following: I want to create objects (airplanes) of the class "Flugzeug" (German word for airplane). I want to create an array which refers to the different attributes of the objects.

The problem is (as far as I know) that one single array can only refer to variables of the exact same type.

How can I change my program that it works? Is it inevitable to create an array for each attribute (e.g. for each different type of variable)?

The code:

```
public class Fluggesellschaft {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Flugzeug [] airline = new Flugzeug [4]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i=i+1){  
            airline[i] = new Flugzeug ();
            airline[0].type = "A320";
            airline[0].idNumber = "1";
            airline[0].seats = "165";
            airline[0].velocity = "890";
            airline[0].range = "12600";
            airline[1].type = "Boeing 747";
            airline[1].idNumber = "2";
            airline[1].seats = "416";
            airline[1].velocity = "907";
            airline[1].range = "12700";
            airline[2].type = "Avro RJ 85";
            airline[2].idNumber = "3";
            airline[2].seats = "93";
            airline[2].velocity = "760";
            airline[2].range = "2200";
            airline[3].type = "Airbus 380";
            airline[3].idNumber = "4";
            airline[3].seats = "516";
            airline[3].velocity = "907";
            airline[3].range = "12000";
        }

        for (int i=0; i < 4; i=i+1) {
            airline[i].printInfo();
            double time = airline[i].getTime(6320);  //distance from Zurich to New York
            System.out.println("duration: " + time + " h");
            int capacity = airline[i].getCapacity(365);
            System.out.println("capacity: " + capacity + " passengers / year");
        }        
   }             
}   


public class Flugzeug {

    String type;
    int idNumber;
    int seats;
    double velocity;
    double range;
    double distance;
    int days;

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println("type: " + this.type);
        System.out.println("ID-number: " +this.idNumber);
        System.out.println("seats: " + this.seats);
        System.out.println("velocity: " + this.velocity);
        System.out.println("range: " + this.range);
    }

    public double getTime (double dist) {
        double result = 0;
        result = dist / velocity;
        double time = result;
        return time;    
    }

    public int getCapacity(int days) {
        int capacity = seats * days;
        return capacity;
    }

}
```

Comment: `idNumber` is an `int`. `"3"` is a `String`. Change the line `airline[0].idNumber = "1";` to `airline[0].idNumber = 1;` (and apply the same change to the other lines like that).

Also, you're assigning the values to each of the 4 objects *inside* the loop that creates the `Flugzeug` objects. That unnecessarily duplicates work and (more importantly) will break when you try to access the second `Flugzeug` in the first loop iteration.

Comment: There are a lot of flaws, but the one that causes your problem is based on the double quotes surrounding the `int` values. E.g. `airline[0].idNumber = "1";` should be `airline[0].idNumber = 1;` because a `Flugzeug` (which should be named `Plane` or `Aeroplane`) has an attribute `idNumber` of type `int`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Why is it bad to assign the values to each of the 4 objects inside the loop? Why does this break? Thank you.

Comment: @Bakeaynado: your code already assigns values to all 4 planes and then you execute that code 4 times, so you're doing 16 assignments, that's unnecessary. And secondly, when you try to access `airline[1]` (or `airline[2]`...) on the *first* time the loop runs then it will not have been assigned a new `Flugzeug` instance yet, so it will crash with a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of your problem is this:

> one single array can only refer to variables of the exact same type.

That is correct (or mostly correct, all elements of an array must have a common base type, but that's not a relevant distinction right now).

But the type inside of your array is `Flugzeug`, not `String`!

So each element of the array must be a `Flugzeug`. That doesn't mean that the *fields of that class* have to all share a single type (and indeed, as you posted, they don't).

Look at this line:

```
airline[0].idNumber = "1";
```

this is *almost* correct, but since `idNumber` is an `int` you must assign it an `int` value (such as `1`) instead:

```
airline[0].idNumber = 1;
```

The second (mostly unrelated) problem is that you try to access all 4 `Flugzeug` instances inside of the loop that creates them. That means when you try to access the second instance after just having created the first one (only!) it will crash:

Replace this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i=i+1) {  
    airline[i] = new Flugzeug ();
    airline[0].type = "A320";
    airline[1].type = "Boeing 747";
    airline[2].type = "Avro RJ 85";
    airline[3].type = "Airbus 380";
}
```

with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i=i+1) {  
    airline[i] = new Flugzeug ();
}
airline[0].type = "A320";
airline[1].type = "Boeing 747";
airline[2].type = "Avro RJ 85";
airline[3].type = "Airbus 380";
```

Comment: And also `airline[0].type = "A320";`, ``airline[1].type = "A320";`` will not work inside loop.

Comment: Thank you. How could I oversee this. Now it its clear: The type is not a simple variable like int or string but a complex variable like Flugzeug (a class). @SudhirOjha: What do you mean? I fixed the problem above and now it displays this error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Fluggesellschaft.main(Fluggesellschaft.java:16)    How can I fix that? Why is there a problem with the line  airline[1].type = "Boeing 747";  Has it something to do with your comment?

Comment: @Bakeaynado The problem is that you are creating the Flugzeug objects inside your loop with `airline[i] = new Flugzeug ();` but then a few line slater use actual indexes and do stuff like `airline[3].range = "12000";`. But in the first iteration of your loop at that point only `airline[0]` will have been initialized and all other indexes still contain null

Comment: Thank you. How should I then use the loop-method to create an array which refers to each airplane (object) and each specification of it?

Comment: @Bakeaynado: since you want each object to have individually determined (non-computed) values, there's no nice way to set the values inside a loop (and also no need). That is, unless you want to take the data from some external source (such as a text file), but that seems to go beyond the scope of what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

if some type like int,double,long... was used " " ,They almost all become String type

Comment: 1 is a int,but "1" is a String

Comment: I'll give you a bad way,If you want to assign any value for idNumber seats velocity... dont used int,double... try Object :),warning! warning!Object will makes your code  Unsafe,just fun,Do not use normally

Answer (score 0):

I found two problems with your code.
First, you have declared idNumber as int `int idNumber;` but while assigning the value you are inserting a string value `airline[0].idNumber = "1";`.
NOTE: "1" is a string not integer.
The solution here would be `airline[0].idNumber = 1;`
You need to assign same type of values to every variable as they are declared.

And second, you are creating multiple objects in the loop `airline[i] = new Flugzeug ();` but overwriting the same single object (stored in the 0th position of the array) everytime. I would suggest to do,

```
airline[i].type = "A320";
airline[i].idNumber = 1;          // Again this should not be "1"
airline[i].seats = 165;           // And this should not be "165"
airline[i].velocity = 890;        // Same is applicable here
airline[i].range = 12600;         // and here
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I saw the problem. But how can I not have the specifications of all airplane-types in the console (output)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the variables are not only `String` type but `int`s and `double`s as well. You need to assign the correct type. In addition you shouldn't access class variables like that, make them `private` create a constructor with getters and setters.

```
public class Flugzeug {
    private String type;
    private int idNumber;
    private int seats;
    private double velocity;
    private double range;
    private double distance;
    private int days;

    public Flugzeug(String type, int idNumber, int seats, double velocity, double range) {
        this.type = type;
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        this.seats = seats;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.range = range;
    }

    public double getDistance() {
        return this.distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}


public class Fluggesellschaft {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flugzeug[] airline = new Flugzeug [4];
        airline[0] = new Flugzeug("A320", 1, 165, 890, 12600);
        airline[1] = new Flugzeug(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am following a tutorial and in there are exercises (this Flugzeug / airplane exercise is one of them). The topic of constructors / private / public has'nt been treated yet. Henceforth, I cannot understand your solution. But I will watch on it again when I learn about these topics.